# robots.txt is blocking root domain

Tags: seo, google

My `robots.txt` is below. Why does my google search console give me an error of "blocked by robots.txt"? It's specifically the root of the domain that is blocked by robots.txt and no other URL. What am I missing? I also tried adding `Allow: /` with no luck

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /u/
Disallow: /wellguide/
```

[image]

Comment: Where in Search Console is it telling you this?  Can you add a screen shot?   When I use Google Search Console robots.txt tester, it says that the home page is allowed with this robots.txt file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy7gp.png

Comment: @StephenOstermiller added

Comment: When did you last update your robots.txt file?  How old is your site? When did you verify the property in Google Search Console?

Comment: I've updated it a few times today to try to get it working, all with variations of the above robots.txt. The site is 2 years old. Verified the property in the console about 6 months ago

Comment: @StephenOstermiller what's weird is that the "live test" keeps working... but the crawl doesn't. and it's just the root domain that is having issues

Comment: Before today, when had you last updated robots.txt?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller november 13th

Comment: Do you have any caching system on the server? Sometimes server cache will keep old robot.txt for a very long time, you should clear it.

Comment: Can you also share your domain?